# wxpython on Wayland is unable to interact with screen coordinates (move a window, GetScreenPosition, etc.)

Tags: python, wxpython, wayland

I found this the hard way. I dove into source code of `wx.lib.agw.aui.framemanager` and tried to figure out why docking hints don't work properly. I have checked every step until in the very end of calculating a place to draw a hint there was a method `ClientToScreen(self,x,y)` which should return `x,y` with an offset of `self: wx.Window`, but returns `x,y` with the same offset every time. Then I tried specifying the starting position in the constructor of my main frame, which didn't have any effect on the position of the frame. Then I checked an output from `GetScreenPosition` while handling `EVT_MOVE` and it turns out that `EVT_MOVE` is not even emitted on Wayland, except when you use `Move` or maximize/minimize the frame (maybe in some other cases, but I have only found mentioned cases).

Inside `EVT_MOVE` handler `GetScreenPosition` returns:

- (0,0) when you maximize the window,
- the coordinates that you specify
  in `Move` when triggered by it (but the `Move` itself doesn't work)
- `(26, 23)` in other cases (including calling it in other places)

Is this a known bug? Maybe I am the only one experiencing it. If not, I will add an issue in wxWidgets/Phoenix.

**edit:** python 3.6.9, wxPython 4.0.7, Ubuntu 18.04.1, Gnome 3.28.4

Comment: I don't think there would be any Python-specific problem for these issues, check if there is already a ticket for it at https://trac.wxwidgets.org/

Comment: @RobinDunn I have made this post before making a ticket because it seems like a very obvious thing to notice. I can't even specify the starting position of a window, yet I haven't seen a single thread/post/ticket/question even mentioning it. And I haven't found a ticket for it with wayland tag (with x it works as intended), so I thought it is a well-known issue or it has something to do with my system (maybe upgrading gnome or installing a specific package would fix it).

Comment: @RobinDunn Given the explanation and link in the answer below, it would be useful to add some information about this non-functionality in the wxPython docs. I have been trying very hard to make wx.Frame.CentreOnScreen() work for a few weeks now. If the docs would have said that this does not work on Wayland, I wouldn't be so sleep deprived as I am right now.

Answer (score 3):

https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/wayland-devel/2015-September/024410.html

> It is a design decision in Wayland/desktop to not expose absolute
>   window positions to clients at all. This means that you simply cannot
>   know where a top-level window is precisely, you can only know which
>   outputs it overlaps with.

You can set an environment variable `GDK_BACKEND=x11` to force Xwayland and the problem is solved. It doesn't seem to be a long term solution, but it works.